# Benefit of reimplementing recursion with manually maintained stack?

Tags: recursion, stack, stack-overflow

I read that maintaining a stack manually could sometimes avoid stack overflow of recursion algorithms, because manually-maintained stack is allocated in heap, which has much larger size than the run-time thread stack. Is there any other benefit of reimplementing recursion with a manually-maintained stack?  Why not just increase that program's stack size, which is much more straightforward?

Answer (score 1):

If you can solve your problem simply by increasing the stack size, that's almost certainly the right solution.

If your algorithm is complex, a manually-maintained stack *might* save you time and space.  You can allocate and free memory exactly when needed and reuse space, especially with multiple or conditional recursion.  If the arguments are of various sizes, you can hold the storage used to only what you need in each call.

*If* you do this well, it's possible that you'll also save time in maintaining argument space ... *if* the algorithm happens to waste time fetching superfluous data with an automatic stack.  I wouldn't count on this.

Reinventing the wheel is generally a bad idea: you have to debug and maintain the new code.  Unless the old wheel was a rectangle ... :-)